# Python/Regex subbing new line with capture group throughout text deletes and rearranges text

Tags: python, regex, lint

Okay so the problem ended up being much different than what I thought it was, but posting it for posterity.

The point of the regex is to lint CPP code, so for this specific pattern I wanted to collapse anything that didn't signal a new line `(';', '{', '}')` would be collapsed.

The pattern is this: r"`(^;{}])[\r\n]\s*`"

1. Capture group 1: find a character outside of the valid set that is followed by:
2. One of the newline characters
3. Eliminate any tabs or spaces for the formatting at the beginning of the next line

This gave me some interesting headaches, but it would basically delete entire lines of code and reorder the remaining lines of code. The problem came down to **Windows uses '\r\n' as it's line break, not just one.**

To fix this, you can either 1) prematurely lint the code for excess line breaks or 2) modify section two of the code to greedy search any amount of newlines. I have had mixed results with just 2, so I recommend using both.

## Broken Code

```
file = open("examplecode2.txt")
self.plain_text = file.read()
file.close()
# this is preprocessing, not related to the problem
self.modified_text = re.sub(r"(\s)+[\r\n]", r"\r\n", self.plain_text)
self.modified_text = re.sub(r"([^;{}])[\n\r]\s*", r"\1", self.modified_text)
```

## Fixed Code

```
file = open("examplecode2.txt")
self.plain_text = file.read()
file.close()
# this is preprocessing, not related to the problem
self.modified_text = re.sub(r"(\s)+[\r\n]", r"\r\n", self.plain_text)
# remove Windows' redundant line breaks
self.modified_text = re.sub(r"\r\n", r"\n", self.modified_text)
# add a greedy catch to the sub
self.modified_text = re.sub(r"([^;{}])[\n\r]+\s*", r"\1", self.modified_text)
```

I'm not sure how many Regex this quirk will apply to, but I could have saved a lot of time if I knew how the double line break would make it act up, so I decided to post this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

(Quoting the question to streamline it)

To fix this, you can either 1) prematurely lint the code for excess line breaks or 2) modify section two of the code to greedy search any amount of newlines. I have had mixed results with just 2, so I recommend using both.

## Fixed Code

```
file = open("examplecode2.txt")
self.plain_text = file.read()
file.close()
# this is preprocessing, not related to the problem
self.modified_text = re.sub(r"(\s)+[\r\n]", r"\r\n", self.plain_text)
# remove Windows' redundant line breaks
self.modified_text = re.sub(r"\r\n", r"\n", self.modified_text)
# add a greedy catch to the sub
self.modified_text = re.sub(r"([^;{}])[\n\r]+\s*", r"\1", self.modified_text)
```